# How to set hint text color in AngularDart Material Components?

Tags: angular-material, material-design, angular-dart

I want to set the hint text color in material-input component in Angular Dart material components -

https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/#/material_input.

How to do it?

There doesn't seem to be any mixin to change the color too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it yourself:

```
material-input ::ng-deep .hint-text {
  color: blue;
}
```

For the Google codebase we require the mixin and it is better to use it externally too because those will get updated on release, but if we don't have one that you need you can always cheat and update the value yourself.

For color it appears we just have material-input-theme which gets you some color changes. I think this was all the flexibility most teams at Google needed.